# .NET class Attribute condition

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, metaprogramming, custom-attributes

Is there a possibility to use an class/method attribute only when a condtion is met? i.e. a registry in the system of a specific value or an app.config setting would indicate, if this custom attribute should be applied to a class? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You'd need to put that condition into whatever's *using* the attribute. The attribute is either applied to the member or not, unconditionally (as it's in the file itself).

Of course you can conditionally apply it or not apply it *at compilation time*, although doing that on the basis of a registry setting or app.config setting would require a bit of trickiness to change the build settings.